# android - Delay thread freezes other activities as well

Tags: android, multithreading, delay

I have a table called actions_table. In it there are the actions that must be taken in the specific order to be taken and they are implemented by seperate services. Everything works fine except the delay action. When there is a delay in the action table the app freezes for as long as the given delay and the weirdest thing is that the other services get executed after the delay even though they are being started before the delay_thread starts!!

I have implemented the delay with a thead and with a while loop checking if system time has passed the start_time + delay_time. same result.

How can i implement this delay without delaying the services launched before the delay? (and without freezing the UI would be nice too)

```
MainActivity{
   onCreate{
       .
       .
       .
       for(i=0;i<actions_table.length;i++){

           if(condition1)
               startService1

           else if(delay_condition2)
                delay_thread.start();

           else if(condition3)
                startService3
       }
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

i finally figured out something that works. sharing what i did for others.

```
delay=0;
for(i=0;i<actions_table.length;i++){
    if(current_action is delay)
        delay=number_of_seconds 
    final Handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run() {

           if(condition1)
               startService1
                .
                .
                .
            else if(conditionX)
                startServiceX
       }
       },delay*1000);
}
```

this way all the actions after of the delay action are executed together the desired number of seconds later. (action1, action2----delay---action3, action4.....actionX)

Comment: Instead of Thread You should use handler,
Using handler you can perform UI operations as well.
it is kind of thread only.which we should use to perform UI operation's

Answer (score 1):

Try this code sample. It works.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do something after 10s = 10000ms


                }
            }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Handler` class `postDelayed` method to not block UI and get delayed `Runnable` to be ran.

```
public boolean condition12ok = true;
public boolean condition34ok = false;

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (condition12ok) {
            action1();
            action2();
            condition12ok = false;
            condition34ok = true
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        } else if (condition34ok) {
            action3();
            action4();
        }
    }
}, 10);
```

So here if none conditions are ok, nothing happens. If condition12ok is true, it runs the actions 1 and 2 then posts same `Runnable` again, then condition 3 and 4 should be ok and the loop stops.

Comment: can you please explain further? how do i use the tool you mentioned?

Comment: I updated my answer to give the idea, how you can poll with Handler and Runnable to do stuff, you can adjust the delay time there if you dont need such fast iterations.

Comment: adding handler.postDelayed(this, delay); inside the handler code calls the handler from within it's self leading to an everlasting call of the handler code. which i don't want. removing this command i'm left with the handler delay that is defined in the end. "},10);" in your code. so if i define the handler in the for loop i have the same delay between all actions. which leads to this[action1...delay...action2...delay...] while what i want to achieve is this [action1,action,2....delay...action3,action4]

(unless i missused your code in which case feel free to correct me)

Comment: You can run action1 and action2 both when some condition is ok, then post same runnable again, run action3 and action4 and do not post the runnable so there is no infinite loop.

Comment: I updated my answer if it helps in your case, if you are having multiple cases, you should not use booleans, instead define state machine with enum or integer which to handle when detecting what you need to run in the Runnable.